# ¿como a agregar el simbolo del $ a los campos de precios de venta y precio de compra que aun no lo consigo?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, datatables

este es el código  de la tabla eta utilizando json para traer los datos de la base de datos y yo quiero agregar el símbolo del $ de lado derecho de los campos de precio de compra y precio de ventas aparte de los datos que trae de la base de datos ejemplo algo así $ 1000 pero en estos momentos solo sale de esta forma 1000  e tratado de incluirlo de muchas formas pero hasta hora ninguna a funcionado la mayoria e las veces me sale un error en el código del json y en otras simple mente no me carga el símbolo del $

```
<?php

        $item = null;

        $valor = null;

        $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($item, $valor);

        foreach ($productos as $key => $value) {
          
          echo '<tr>
                  <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
                  <td><img src="vistas/img/productos/default/anonymous.png" class="img-thumbnail" width="40px"></td>
                  <td>'.$value["codigo"].'</td>
                  <td>'.$value["descripcion"].'</td>';

                  $item = "id";
                  $valor = $value["id_categoria"];

                  $categoria = ControladorCategorias::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

                 echo '<td>'.$categoria["categoria"].'</td>
                  <td>'.$value["stock"].'</td>
                  <td> '.$value["precio_compra"].'</td>
                  <td> '.$value["precio_venta"].'</td>
                  <td>'.$value["fecha"].'</td>
                  <td>

                    <div class="btn-group">
                        
                      <button class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>

                      <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

                    </div>  

                  </td>

                </tr>';

        }

        ?>
                 
        </tbody> -->

       </table>

      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

esta es la parte del código del ajax.php

```
class TablaProductos{

    /*=============================================
     MOSTRAR LA TABLA DE PRODUCTOS
    =============================================*/ 

    public function mostrarTablaProductos(){

        $item = null;
        $valor = null;

        $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($item, $valor);  
        
        $datosJson = '{
          "data": [';

          for($i = 0; $i < count($productos); $i++){

            /*=============================================
            TRAEMOS LA IMAGEN
            =============================================*/ 

            $imagen = "<img src='".$productos[$i]["imagen"]."' width='40px'>";

            /*=============================================
            TRAEMOS LA CATEGORÍA
            =============================================*/ 

            $item = "id";
            $valor = $productos[$i]["id_categoria"];

            $categorias = ControladorCategorias::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

            /*=============================================
            STOCK
            =============================================*/ 

            if($productos[$i]["stock"] <= 10){

                $stock = "<button class='btn btn-danger'>".$productos[$i]["stock"]."</button>";

            }else if($productos[$i]["stock"] > 11 && $productos[$i]["stock"] <= 15){

                $stock = "<button class='btn btn-warning'>".$productos[$i]["stock"]."</button>";

            }else{

                $stock = "<button class='btn btn-success'>".$productos[$i]["stock"]."</button>";

            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAEMOS LAS ACCIONES
            =============================================*/ 

            $botones =  "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditarProducto'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' codigo='".$productos[$i]["codigo"]."' imagen='".$productos[$i]["imagen"]."'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></div>"; 

            $datosJson .='[
                  "'.($i+1).'",
                  "'.$imagen.'",
                  "'.$productos[$i]["codigo"].'",
                  "'.$productos[$i]["descripcion"].'",
                  "'.$categorias["categoria"].'",
                  "'.$stock.'",
                  "'.$productos[$i]["precio_compra"].'",
                  "'.$productos[$i]["precio_venta"].'",
                  "'.$productos[$i]["fecha"].'",
                  "'.$botones.'"
                ],';

          }

          $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);

         $datosJson .=   '] 

         }';
        
        echo $datosJson;


    }


}
```

Comment: Por qué no lo concatenas? ``$variable . '$';``

Comment: @AndySamuel te refieres en la parte del  `"'.$categorias["categoria"].'". '$' ,` o en esta `<td> '.$value["precio_compra"].'.'$'</td>`

Comment: Colócalo en la celda ``<td> '.$value["precio_compra"].'$</td>``

Comment: muchas gracias en verdad tu comentario ha sido de mucha ayuda @AndySamuel